# How can I decrypt a SHA256 Hash string when I know the answer is a random number from a known nuimber range?

Tags: encryption, hash, sha256, salt, sha

A random number is selected from a range of 1 to 50 (for example). 
This number then encrypted with a salt key to a SHA256 Hash string.
What I wanted to know is if there is any way I can decrypt this Hash String to get the encrypted random number behind it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SHA256 is not an encryption algorithm and therefore its output can't be decrypted (because it's not encrypted)

Comment: So is there any other way to get the encrypted number?

Comment: Yes, brute-force the combination of number and salt

Comment: Can you walk me through it? Write an answer if you can please so that it'll really be of help to me and my fellow classmates. Thanks

Comment: First, you need to read up on differences between hashing and encryption. I'm hoping this alone would answer your question.

Comment: And by "brute-force" I meant "try all possible combinations of numbers and salts, and hash them in the same way. If this combination yields the same hash as you have, then you have "found" the number". Of course, this becomes much easier if the salt is known.

Comment: what if the salt is unknown?

Comment: Then you need to guess it too

Comment: a little hint here ... if you find the same hash by this approach, in general you can not be sure that you have found the original input: what you might find this way is an input that results in the given hash ... there might be other input + salt combinations that lead to the exact same hash... so what you can find by brute force is a so called collision ... in terms of your case, you will need to exaustively search all possible combinations of your number and salt space to see if there is another possible candidate or if you really found the only one